# Cannot block IP range using special chain in iptables

Tags: ip, iptables

I have a script to block any IP range with which I am being sync flooded.  I have created a chain called SYNC_FLOOD to which is temporarily added the highest level of the CIDR address of a flooding IP address, in the form of (example) 171.0.0.0/8.  My problem is that the SYNC_FLOOD chain doesn't block the address, whereas if I manually put the above address into the iptables INPUT chain, it does get blocked.  Can anyone see or know what is wrong here?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this further, do I need to add this line to my SYNC_FLOOD for it to work?

iptables -A INPUT -j SYNC_FLOOD